# Best Landsat band for forest classification?

Tags: qgis, remote-sensing, classification, landsat, band

Using Qgis and the Semi-Automatic Plugin for Classification, which are the best Landsat bands to use to classify trees species (in central Argentina)? In Landsat 5, 7 and 8?

Comment: what kind of species exist in your area of interest? maybe you can read this [Discrimination of araucaria forests (Araucaria araucana) in the Conguillio National Park, Southern-Center Chile, using Landsat TM data](http://mingaonline.uach.cl/pdf/bosque/v32n2/art02.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: *all of them*.  Most classification algorithms can derive useful information from all of the bands.  However, there are certainly bands that are better at discriminating between vegetation types.  You may also want to incorporate band indices such as [NDVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_Difference_Vegetation_Index) or [EVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_vegetation_index) into your classification algorithm.  NASA produced some useful tables to help answer *What are the best spectral bands to use for my study?* ([Source](http://landsat.usgs.gov/best_spectral_bands_to_use.php)):

**Landsat 8 Operational Land Imager (OLI) and Thermal Infrared Sensor (TIRS)**

[image]

**Landsat 4-5 Thematic Mapper (TM) and Landsat 7 Enhanced Thematic Mapper Plus (ETM+)**

[image]

Comment: Thanks: you make me think I could try to classify upon an Indice (NDVI or EVI).

Comment: @Inclanfunk Indeed, incorporating NDVI and/or EVI into your raster stack is a common practice for classification.